# Irreducible representations of $SO(3)$

Tags: quantum-spin, representation-theory

Let $\pi_l:so(3)\rightarrow gl(v)$ be the Lie Algebra representation of $so(3)$, with spin $l$ half-integer. Let $F_3$ be one of the canonical basis of the Lie Algebra, in particular

$$ F_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1  &0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Define the operator $L_3:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ as $ L_3 = i\pi_l(F_3)$, which acts on vectors $L_3v_j=(l-1)v_j$. My textbook,"Quantum Theory for Mathematicians", reports the following formula, which I can't seem to prove

$$e^{2\pi \pi_l(F_3)} = e^{2\pi i L_3} = -I$$

I really don't understand how it gets from the second expression to the third. $I$ is the the identity operator. I think the fact that $l$ is half-integer plays a crucial role, but I can't see how.

EDIT: in the formula above, the former $\pi$ is the actual number, while the latter is the representation.

Comment: I think you need the 1/2's in the spinor rep of $SO\left( 3 \right)$ in order to see that: $$\exp2\pi i\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1/2 & 0\\
0 & -1/2
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
e^{\pi i} & 0\\
0 & e^{-\pi i}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Does $L_3$ act that way on *all* vectors? So it's proportional to the identity operator?

Comment: Thanks @joigus, $L_3$ is diagonal and therefore the exponential is the one you wrote.